# Cannot access Webservice when I use the IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web, wsdl

We have an application developed in asp.net. I have a peculiar scenario here

We can access the application with its ip address for ex

http://10.10.10.10/myApp

We use webservices for some of the functions, the webservices reside on the same machine where the application is hosted. The WSDL URL would be like

http://10.10.10.10/myApp/WebService.asmx?WSDL

The WSDL url are accessed from a non cached Javascript file.

So far it was good for us, and we never faced issues.

Now recently we had some restrictions in our company and we had to create a FQDN name for our application.
The application FQDN name is

http://abc.xyz.com/myApp

But the WSDL url that uses the webservices is still

http://10.10.10.10/myApp/WebService.asmx?WSDL

When we try to access the application with FQDN name it is failing while calling the web services. (The IP did not change while creating the FQDN).

When I change the code to access the web service with the new WSDL URL

http://abc.xyz.com/myApp/WebService.asmx?WSDL

it is completely working fine.

Now the problem here is again it would fail if some one is using the application with the IP address instead of the FQDN name. Is there a way to solve this issue. (I need to call the web-service, no matter if I launch the application with the ip address or FQDN name)

Hope I am clear. Thanks in advance for your help !!

(PS: This issue happens only in internet explorer 10, when used from the previous versions it works completely fine)

Comment: Open your ASMX file and see if any URL is embedded inside iyour ASMX file.

Comment: Also, you can post the fake URL's without having to type out colon. Along as it's sufficiently anonymized then you don't have a security risk. For example, http://10.10.10.10/myApp/WebService.asmx?WSDL

Comment: <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/CPTService.cs" Class="CPTService" %>  This is the amsx file. No hard coding anywhere : (